# Handle Javascript onclick function in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, webkit

I have a button inside a web view. 
When the button is clicked, I would like to add the item to my native code array.
Then, when it's pressed again, I would like to remove the item in the array.

My question is: What's missing in the logic? Neither `userContentController` or `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` is called when the button is pressed.

The JavaScript Code

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 function someFunction(id) {
  if(id = true) {
    document.getELementById("someid").innerText = " some title state 1"
  } else {
     document.getELementById(someid).innerText = " some title state 2"
  }
 }
<script>
```

The Html Button

```
<button class=someclass id="someid" onclick= "Some.listCallBack()">Add List</button>
```

The Objective C code

```
TableViewCell.h
@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell <WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler>
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;
 
TableViewCell.m

- (void)awakeFromNib {
 [[[self.webView configuration] userContentController]addScriptMessageHandler:selfname:@"someid"];
}
​
- (void)userContentController:(nonnull WKUserContentController *)userContentController 
didReceiveScriptMessage:(nonnull WKScriptMessage *)message {
// i will handle event here 

}
```

Comment: What’s `Some.listCallback()`? Whatever is missing (or isn’t missing) seems to be in there.

Comment: its a javascript callcack

Answer (score 1):

Since the actual click handler seems to be omitted from the question, it’s hard to tell what the exact problem is. I might therefore be stating the obvious, but here we go.

The handler (the one registered with `-addScriptMessageHandler:name:`) is exposed to JavaScript as a property on `webkit.messageHandlers`. From there, the interprocess communication looks more or less like messaging another window, except instead of `window.postMessage()` we use `webkit.messageHandlers.handlerID.postMessage()`. In other words,

```
function clickHandler() {
    webkit.messageHandlers.someid.postMessage("The message we’d like to pass to our WKScriptMessageHandler");
}
```

should do.